# Installing bbcp on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, homebrew, file-transfer, scp

I'm trying to install [bbcp](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/~abh/bbcp/) (which is a fast scp alternative) on MAC, I tried with brew:

```
$ brew install bbcp
Error: No available formula for bbcp
==> Searching formulae...
==> Searching taps...
homebrew/head-only/bbcp
```

It looks like the [bbcp binaries](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/~abh/bbcp/bin/) are not available for OS X! Any idea how to port them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to port it. [bbcp](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/~abh/bbcp/) for OS X is available [here](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/~abh/bbcp/bin/amd64_darwin_100/bbcp). After downloading and moving it to an appropriate folder (e.g. /usr/local/bin) modify ownership and make the file executable.

Version number is: 15.02.03.01.1

Comment: I can't execute it. I get "Segmentation fault: 11". Do you know how I can make it work? Thanks

Comment: @DiegoMazón What's your system version?